# How to get the value returned by count in Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, group-by, sql-server-2012

I have the following sql query:

```
Select Invoices.ID, count(*) invoices
From
   Customers.ID F
   Inner join Invoices p
   On P.ID=F.ID and f.ID = 1
group by p.ID
GO
```

What I want to do is use the count(*) invoices in a if statement after the group by p.ID, however I do not seem to be able to find a way to get to that value. I know that I can do a row count by eliminating the group by clause but I would really prefer to get the count(*) invoices value.

```
Select Invoices.ID, count(*) invoices
From
   Customers.ID F
   Inner join Invoices p
   On P.ID=F.ID and f.ID = 1
group by p.ID
if ("value from count(*) invoices) = 0
  do some stuff here
else
  do some other stuff here
GO
```

Thank you for you help.
Shimon

Answer (score 0):

Put the value in a variable. Something like this:

```
declare @invoice_id int;
declare @myCount int;

Select @invoice_id = Invoices.ID, @myCount = count(*)
From
   Customers.ID F
   Inner join Invoices p
   On P.ID=F.ID and f.ID = 1
group by p.ID
if (@myCount) = 0
  do some stuff here
else
  do some other stuff here
GO
```

Comment: A select statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data retrieval operations

Comment: @Shimon I forgot the invoice id. Try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Case statement in the query

```
Select Invoices.ID, 
Case When count(*)=0 
 then "do something" 
 else "do something" end AS invoices
From
   Customers.ID F
   Inner join Invoices p
   On P.ID=F.ID and f.ID = 1
group by p.ID
GO
```